# EF POCO change nullable<bool> to bool and set default value

Tags: entity-framework

How I can set default value false for bool property in poco object? Column in db has type bit, null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
public partial class MyPocoObject
{
    public MyPocoObject()
    {
         MyBoolProperty = false;
    }
}
```